# R storing different columns in different vectors to compute conditional probabilities

Tags: r, vector, probability, multiple-columns

I am completely new to R. I tried reading the reference and a couple of good introductions, but I am still quite confused.

I am hoping to do the following:

I have produced a .txt file that looks like the following:

```
area,energy 
1.41155882174e-05,1.0914586287e-11
1.46893363946e-05,5.25011714434e-11
1.39244046855e-05,1.57904991488e-10
1.64155121046e-05,9.0815757601e-12
1.85202830392e-05,8.3207522281e-11
1.5256036289e-05,4.24756620609e-10
1.82107587343e-05,0.0
```

I have the following command to read the file in R:

```
tbl <- read.csv("foo.txt",header=TRUE).
```

producing:

```
> tbl
           area       energy
1 1.411559e-05 1.091459e-11
2 1.468934e-05 5.250117e-11
3 1.392440e-05 1.579050e-10
4 1.641551e-05 9.081576e-12
5 1.852028e-05 8.320752e-11
6 1.525604e-05 4.247566e-10
7 1.821076e-05 0.000000e+00
```

Now I want to store each column in two different vectors, respectively `area` and `energy`.

I tried:

```
area <- c(tbl$first)
energy <- c(tbl$second)
```

but it does not seem to work.

I need to different vectors (which must include only the numerical data of each column) in order to do so:

```
> prob(energy, given = area), i.e. the conditional probability P(energy|area).
```

And then plot it. Can you help me please?

Comment: Why `tbl$first` and not `tbl$area`? And why did you wrap it in `c()`?

Comment: Call the columns of your dataframe by their names: `tbl$area` and `tbl$energy`, or position: `tbl[,1]` and `tbl[,2]`. No need to store them as separate vectors to use them later.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ananda Mahto alluded to, the problem is in the way you are referring to columns.

To 'get' a column of a data frame in `R`, you have several options:

```
DataFrameName$ColumnName
DataFrameName[,ColumnNumber]
DataFrameName[["ColumnName"]]
```

So to get `area`, you would do:

```
tbl$area #or
tbl[,1]  #or
tbl[["area"]]
```

With the first option generally being preferred (from what I've seen).

Incidentally, for your 'end goal', you don't need to do any of this:

```
with(tbl, prob(energy, given = area))
```

does the trick.

Comment: I'd recommend being familiar with the R FAQ before coming to SO for help - this is a pretty basic topic.


http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf

Comment: I tried it. I get this message: Error in x$probs : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: what happens when you run `names(x)` and `class(x)`

Comment: Respectively: NULL and numeric.

Comment: Ok then your problem is that `x` isn't a data frame.